# AngularJS - Not firing / fetching Http Request at all

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I am new to Angular and below is the simple code which should fetch data from the http urls and display :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="galaxyCtrlA"> 
    <p>The $http service requests responses from the the server on the "Zone of Avoidance" galaxies, and the response are set as the values of the "message" and "pictures" variables.</p>
    <p>Welcome message from the "Zone of Avoidance" galaxies is:</p>
       <h1>{{ message }}</h1>

    <p>The pictures from the "Zone of Avoidance" are:</p>
     <ul>
      <br/>
      <li ng-repeat="p in pictures">
        <img src="{{ p.image }}" alt="{{ p.image }}" width="60%" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('galaxyCtrlA', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.bogotobogo.com/AngularJS/files/httpRequest/welcome.html")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.message = response.data;
    });

    $http.get("http://www.bogotobogo.com/AngularJS/files/httpRequest/picture-list.json")
    .success(function(response) {
       $scope.pictures = response.image;
    });
  });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output for the above should be pretty simple but i get a blank page , no errors at all .

Kindly advice what's going wrong

Comment: Is this also the domain you're using? Also looking at the files, looks like `response.image` would be empty

Comment: No this isnt a domain i am using . Its a different domain .

Comment: Before marking this as duplicate kindly understand what i am asking and if the output are the same rather than trying to act too smart . @Pankaj Parkar

Comment: @user1411837 apologies, do you have collcetion inside `response.image`?

Comment: CORS Need to be enabled from the server side and 
The second http request is returning you just the image name in text i guess.

Comment: Were you able to solve This? Was my answer helpful at all?

Comment: Are you still struggling with this one? Please share an update when you can

Answer (score 1):

That endpoint does not return an object with an `.image` property, but is instead an array of objects each with that property.

> [ { image:
>   "/AngularJS/files/httpRequest/Stills_Cam-4_Frame-1300_adjusted.jpg" },
>   { image: "/AngularJS/files/httpRequest/14-scientistsdi.jpg" } ]

Try instead assigning your `$scope` object to the `response.data` object property. Also note that `.success` is deprecated in favor of `.then`

```
$http.get("http://www.bogotobogo.com/AngularJS/files/httpRequest/picture-list.json")
    .then(function(response) {
       $scope.pictures = response.data;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the second request.
It should be :

```
$http.get("http://www.bogotobogo.com/AngularJS/files/httpRequest/picture-list.json")
    .success(function(response) {
       $scope.pictures = response;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks But sorry that didnt make any difference

Answer (score 0):

It is not parsing the json in my test. Does this work?

```
$http.get("picture-list.json").success(function(response) {

    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    $scope.pictures = data.image;
});
```

Here is a json string that i know is working: 
      "{\"image\":[{\"image\":\"url.jpg\"}]}"